# How can I get members with that dont have active subscriptions?

Tags: sql

I have two tables members and subscriptions.

#### members table

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

#### subscriptions table

| id | member id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-08-05 | 2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-07-20 | 2023-10-11 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-09-01 | 2023-10-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-08-09 | 2023-11-02 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-06-01 | 2023-07-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-05-03 | 2023-06-21 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-06-21 | 2023-07-25 |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-26 |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-11-04 |

I want to get members in a joined table where they don't have any subscription that has start_date < today and end date > today. Which means active subscription in my case. I also want to get latest ended subscription's start_date and end_date for acquired table such as;

let's assume today is 2023-07-31:

#### required result table

| id (member_id) | start_date(latest_sub start_date) | end_date(latest_sub end_date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-06-01 | 2023-07-01 |
| 3 | 2023-06-21 | 2023-07-25 |
| 5 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-26 |

How can I achive it with sql? thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: which DBMS do you use there?

Comment: I am using sqllite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can apparently have multiple subscriptions for any given member you won't be able to make the determination by looking only at individual rows.

```
select member_id,
    case when min(end_date) > '2023-07-31'
         then min(start_date)
         else max(case when start_date < '2023-07-31'
                       then start_date end) end as s_dt,
    case when min(start_date) > '2023-07-31'
         then min(end_date)
         else max(case when start_date < '2023-07-31'
                       then end_date end) end as e_dt
from subscriptions
where member_id not in (
    select member_id from subscriptions
    where '2023-07-31' between start_date and end_date
)
group by member_id;
```

This assumes that the end date is included in the range of valid dates and that you don't have any weird overlapping subscription ranges. You can probably use a CTE to avoid repeating the same date value over and over. See the linked fiddle for an example of that.

Your sample does have a case where all of the subscriptions follow the reference date and you seem to want the earliest date values to be returned rather than the latest. The additional logic is looking for such a case whereas the default behavior is to look only at subscriptions that had already ended.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n4jPDZwLAyRa4Q9vHMPvnx/1

Comment: thank you for your answer! here is another challenge: 1-how can I get users that have all subscriptions past? 2- How can I get users with at least one 
furter starting subscription? by earlier dates of course.

Comment: @Burak `case when max(start_date) < <date> then 1 else 0 end = 1 /* AllPast */, case when max(start_date) > <date> then 1 else 0 end = 1 /* Future */`

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
SELECT member_id FROM subscriptions WHERE CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

wich will select the member_id as you ask.
You can learn more about `GETDATE()` on [this tutorial](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-time-in-t-sql/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20current%20date%20and%20time%20in%20SQL%20Server,put%20anything%20in%20the%20brackets.)

If `GETDATE()` doesn't work, please consider tagging your DMS in the post.

Edit : You can get the members informations doing a subrequestion like this :

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = (SELECT member_id FROM subscriptions WHERE CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;);
```

wich will look for the members having the same id as the result of the ids in the previous request

Comment: thanks for your response. How can I get resulting members as joined table?

Comment: You can get the members informations doing a subrequestion like this : `SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = (SELECT member_id FROM subscriptions WHERE start_date < CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) AND end_date > CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ));` wich will look for the members having the same id as the result of the ids in the previous request.

Edit : I added it in the answer too

Comment: I wonder, why we can't use NOT BETWEEN here? would reduce the repetition of this CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )

Comment: yeah good advice, I'll edit to add the NOT BETWEEN thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also want to get member's latest ended subscription's start_date and end_date on a single query along with member. How can I achive that? thanks again.

Comment: To get the last subscrptions for each member you can execute the query `SELECT TOP 1 FROM subscriptions WHERE end_date < CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) ORDER BY end_date ASC;`

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it. If you need other SQL request, consider editing your post or create another post with all the request you need.

Comment: I have edited question can you please look at that?

Comment: Something like this `Select member_id, sub2.start_date ,sub1.end_date 
From member, 
(SELECT TOP 1 FROM subscriptions WHERE end_date < CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) ORDER BY member_id, end_date ASC) as sub1, 
(SELECT TOP 1 FROM subscriptions WHERE start_date < CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) ORDER BY member_id, start_date ASC) As sub2
WHERE member.id=sub1.member_id
AND member.id=sub2.member_id;` might work but this start to go far into SQL so I won't be able to help furthermore